# Wordpress $wpdb no result

Tags: mysql, wpdb

I have the following code in my functions.php

```
$code = 'EUR';
global $wpdb;
$query = 'SELECT * FROM ';
$query .= $wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . 'fxbase ';
$query .= 'WHERE code= '.$code;
$data = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare( $query ), ARRAY_A );
```

The problem is the above query does not give any result. Just to test the following query in mysql is working fine:

```
SELECT * FROM `1621_fxbase` WHERE `code` = 'EUR'
```

Not really able to figure out what is the issue here.

Comment: you're not using prepare correctly, see the examples [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) and [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#Database)

Comment: @Milo I am using the same code in my plugin file where it works as expected. Is there any difference as to how wordpress works with my_plugin.php and functions.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specific issue in that code is that you're missing the quote marks around the $code.

`$query .= 'WHERE code= '.$code;`

Should be:

`$query .= 'WHERE code= "'.$code.'"';`

In the long run, you should indeed use prepare() properly, but this is the specific problem with the code you posted.

Comment: BTW, note that if $code isn't hardcoded like you have there, and is subject to user modification, then your code has an SQL Injection Exploit in it.

Answer (score 0):

### `prepare()` the right way

Things that don't need prepare: Default objects from `$wpdb` (make a dump to see what it got)

- Everything that's built into core: Table names, "Field", Row & Column names

Everything else **must** get prepared. And this isn't only user input, but also everything else like custom table, "field", row & column names.

Rule of thumb: Prepare as late as possible and let come nothing between the preparation and the query (if possible).

You can only prepare two things:

- `%s` = strings
- `%d` = digits

### Example

Try it like this:

```
// functions.php
function wpse73348_custom_table_query_test( $dump = false )
{
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->flush();
    $result = $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare(
         "
            SELECT * FROM %s
            WHERE `code` = %s
         "
        ,$wpdb->get_blog_prefix().'fxbase '
        ,$code
    ), ARRAY_A );
    0 >= $wpdb->num_rows AND $result = 'No result from query';

    if ( ! $dump )
        return $result;

    // Debug result
    echo '<pre>'.var_export( $result, true )
         "\n Addt. Info: \n".var_export( $wpdb->last_result, true ).var_export( $wpdb->last_query, true ).var_export( $wpdb->col_info, true ).'</pre>';
}

// In some template.php
wpse73348_custom_table_query_test( true );
```

Comment: The above code still does not show any result. var_dump on $result gives NULL bool(true). If however, I search in the column 'id' (primary), I do get a result, which I was getting from the original code as well that I was using. The column 'code' in mysql is of datatype varchar if that could be causing any error.

Comment: @kaiser: You should not have the backticks around the %s, nor should you need run the table name through prepare (it won't work if you do). I'll edit your post to correct.

Comment: @Otto Yeah, you're right. I copy/pasted most of his code - my wrong. Just edited to ... damn.

Comment: @Otto We were editing in parallel. There's much more crap in there. `echo '<pre>'.var_dump(...` won't work either.

Comment: I'm done, feel free to fix it.

Comment: @Otto Yeah, did anyway.